# Probability density function (for which $a,b$)

Tags: probability, expected-value, density-function

Let $f_{a,b}(x)=(\frac{x}{4}-\frac{1}{2})\boldsymbol{1}_{(a,b)}(x)$, with $\boldsymbol{1}$ is the indicator function.

For which $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is $f$ a probability density function? Also, how to compute the expected value?

I tried this:

Since the function $\frac{x}{4}-\frac{1}{2}$ has a root at $x=2,$ I integrated from $b$ to $2$:

$\int_{b}^{2} \frac{x}{4}-\int_{b}^{2} \frac{1}{2} dx=1$

$\left[\frac{x}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\right]_b^2=1$

$\left[\frac{x^3}{3}+x\right]_1^2=1$

$=-\frac{b^2}{8}-\frac{1}{2}b-\frac{1}{2}$

I put $2$ in the formula: $2(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8}a)-1=0$ and got $2+\sqrt{8}.$

Now I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is a probability density function if it is positive and its integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is $1$.

**Positivity:**

$f$ is positive iff :

$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, (\dfrac{x-2}{4}) \mathbb{1}_{(a, b)} (x) \geq 0
$$

$\Leftrightarrow$

$$
\forall x \in (a, b), (\dfrac{x-2}{4}) \mathbb{1}_{(a, b)} (x) \geq 0
$$

$\Leftrightarrow$

$$
\forall x \in (a, b), \dfrac{x-2}{4} \geq 0
$$ 
$\Leftrightarrow$

$$
\dfrac{a-2}{4}\geq 0 \textrm{ and } \dfrac{b-2}{4}\geq 0
$$

$\Leftrightarrow$

$$
a, b \geq 2 
$$

**Integral is $1$**

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f = \int_{a}^b \dfrac{x-2}{4} dx = \dfrac{1}{16} (b - a) (b+a - 4) 
$$

So we must have $(a, b)$ belong to some hyperbola. See here [for the definition of hyperbola](https://www.mathway.com/popular-problems/Pre-Algebra/167344).